# Find values based on one column table from another table.Pivot

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, group-by, pivot

Help needed.

I have three tables

1. `Building_master` - columns: BuildingCode, Building Name
2. `Floor_master` - columns: FloorCode, Floor Name, BuildingCode
3. `Room_Master` - columns: RoomCode, RoomName, RoomFloor, RoomBulding

I want to fill the GridView when I select `Building Name` from `Building_master` table where the output will be something like below

```
Building Name: A

Floor               
1   Room 101    Room 102    Room 103    Room 104
2   Room 201    Room 202    Room 203
3   Room 301    Room 302    Room 303    Room 304
```

Kindly help to create a SQL query for the desired output

Comment: what is the relation between ``Floor_master`` and `Room_Master`? i think between ``Building_master`` and ``Floor_master`` is `BuildingCode`.

Comment: FloorCode and building code in room master

Comment: ok, check @GMB answer.

Answer (score 1):

To pivot over a fixed number of columns (that is, the maximum number of rooms per floor), you can join, then use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select  
    building_name,
    floor_name,
    max(case when rn = 1 then room_name end) room1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then room_name end) room2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then room_name end) room3
from (
    select
        b.building_code,
        b.building_name,
        f.floor_code,
        f.floor_name,
        r.room_name,
        row_number() over(
            partition by b.building_code, f.floor_code order by r.room_code
        ) rn
    from building_master b
    inner join floor_master f
        on f.building_code = b.building_code
    inner join room_master r 
        on  r.room_floor = f.floor_code 
        and r.room_building = b.building_code
) t
group by b.building_code, b.building_name, f.floor_code, f.floor_name
```

I had to make a few guesses about the relationships in your schema, that you might need to review.

You can handle more rooms by floor by adding more `max()` expressions to the outer `select`.

Comment: I have tried this but it is not working, please help

Comment: select b002,f002 
  max(case when rn=1 then roo2 end)415
  max(case when rn=2 then roo2 end)416
  from(
  select b.b002,b.b003,f.f002,f.f003,
  row_number() over(
  partition by b.f002,f.f002 order by r.r002
  ) rn
  from building_master b
  inner join floor_master f
  on f.f006=b.b002
  inner join room_master r
  on r.r004=f.f002 
  and r.r008=b.b002
  ) t
  group by b.b002,b.b003,f.f002,f.f003

Comment: Actual Database fields are as below   Table : Building Master   building code:b002 , Building name: b003     Floor Master: Floor Code:f002, FLoor name: f002 Building Code:f006 and Room_master : Roome Code :r002 , roome name:r003 ,room floor:r004 and building Code:r008